# Rspecs Failed with Test::Unit automatic runner messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

versions

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
rails-3.2.18
rspec-2.14.1
parallel_tests-0.9.3
```

configs

.rspec

```
--color
--format documentation
--drb
--profile
```

.rspec_parallel

```
If installed as plugin: -I vendor/plugins/parallel_tests/lib
--color
--format documentation
--profile
```

when normal rspec success and not output Test unit messages

```
% RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec
```

when parallel_tests rspec failed and output Test Unit messages

```
% RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake parallel:create\[4\] db:migrate parallel:prepare\[4\]
% RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake parallel:spec\[4\]
```

error

```
invalid option: -O
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/anyone.develop.spec/workspace/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rspec [options] [-- untouched arguments]
    -r, --runner=RUNNER              Use the given RUNNER.
                                     (c[onsole], e[macs], x[ml])
        --collector=COLLECTOR        Use the given COLLECTOR.
                                     (de[scendant], di[r], l[oad], o[bject]_space)
    -n, --name=NAME                  Runs tests matching NAME.
                                     (patterns may be used).
        --ignore-name=NAME           Ignores tests matching NAME.
                                     (patterns may be used).
    -t, --testcase=TESTCASE          Runs tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
                                     (patterns may be used).
        --ignore-testcase=TESTCASE   Ignores tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
                                     (patterns may be used).
        --location=LOCATION          Runs tests that defined in LOCATION.
                                     LOCATION is one of PATH:LINE, PATH or LINE
        --attribute=EXPRESSION       Runs tests that matches EXPRESSION.
                                     EXPRESSION is evaluated as Ruby's expression.
                                     Test attribute name can be used with no receiver in EXPRESSION.
                                     EXPRESSION examples:
                                       !slow
                                       tag == 'important' and !slow
        --[no-]priority-mode         Runs some tests based on their priority.
        --default-priority=PRIORITY  Uses PRIORITY as default priority
                                     (h[igh], i[mportant], l[ow], m[ust], ne[ver], no[rmal])
    -I, --load-path=DIR[:DIR...]     Appends directory list to $LOAD_PATH.
        --color-scheme=SCHEME        Use SCHEME as color scheme.
                                     (d[efault])
        --config=FILE                Use YAML fomat FILE content as configuration file.
        --order=ORDER                Run tests in a test case in ORDER order.
                                     (a[lphabetic], d[efined], r[andom])
        --max-diff-target-string-size=SIZE
                                     Shows diff if both expected result string size and actual result string size are less than or equal SIZE in bytes.
                                     (1000)
    -v, --verbose=[LEVEL]            Set the output level (default is verbose).
                                     (important-only, n[ormal], p[rogress], s[ilent], v[erbose])
        --[no-]use-color=[auto]      Uses color output
                                     (default is auto)
        --progress-row-max=MAX       Uses MAX as max terminal width for progress mark
                                     (default is auto)
        --no-show-detail-immediately Shows not passed test details immediately.
                                     (default is yes)
        --output-file-descriptor=FD  Outputs to file descriptor FD
        --                           Stop processing options so that the
                                     remaining options will be passed to the
                                     test.
    -h, --help                       Display this help.

Deprecated options:
        --console                    Console runner (use --runner).

Coverage report Rcov style generated for RSpec to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/anyone.develop.spec/workspace/coverage/rcov
Rspecs Failed
```

try to

https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/189

add spec_helper.rb

```
Test::Unit::AutoRunner.need_auto_run = false if defined?(Test::Unit::AutoRunner)
```

But, It did not resolve

delete spork

add

```
Test::Unit::AutoRunner.need_auto_run = false if defined?(Test::Unit::AutoRunner)
```

spec_helper.rb last line

resolved!

Comment: Adding `Test::Unit::AutoRunner.need_auto_run = false if defined?(Test::Unit::AutoRunner)` to spec_helper.rb also resolved for me!

Answer (score 2):

try this on your Gemfile

```
gem "test-unit", :require => false
```

or try test-unit 3.1.5.

https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/issues/32#issuecomment-146885235
someone says about broke the application to run on Heroku. but likely the same as your problem